Importrange + Substitute how to write the correct syntax
I'm using Google Spreadsheets.
Column E of the sheet name has a long sentence with multiple line breaks. I want to remove this line break and get it.
I tried using the code below, but it failed. The where is working fine, so if I remove the newline in the reference source, I can get it correctly. Please tell me how to write the correct syntax to automatically remove line breaks.
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(
 {TO_TEXT(IMPORTRANGE("URL_SPREADSHEET","sheet_name!A:E")};

"select * where

Col3= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A2&"' or 
Col4= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A2&"' or 
Col5= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A2&"' or 
Col3= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A3&"' or 
Col4= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A3&"' or 
Col5= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A3&"' or 
Col3= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A4&"' or 
Col4= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A4&"' or 
Col5= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A4&"' or 
Col3= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A5&"' or 
Col4= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A5&"' or 
Col5= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A5&"' or 
Col3= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A6&"' or 
Col4= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A6&"' or 
Col5= '"&'sheet_name_keyword'!A6&"'
")
"sheet_name!E:E", CHAR(10), ""
)))

▼Reference source data sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1eLa3mTf4_KBHE4dHdu6mVLenTKpea0x72OrDnKv1olQ/edit?gid=1122809158#gid=1122809158
▼Sheet that displays the obtained results https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KLkmq2yD_KefsqM0So20Qq84jSs76OySWwOQWtytyEY/edit?gid=0#gid=0
I would like to refer to the row that contains the keyword set in sheet_name_keyword,
but I can't seem to find it properly because the data in column E contains multiple line breaks.
There I am trying to use SUBSTITUTE to remove line breaks and get it.
It is easier to see if there is a line break even after getting it, so if there is a way to get it without removing the line break, I would like to know.

This is off-topic here, but wherever you wind up, consider telling people which spreadsheet application you are using. Google Sheets, Microsoft Excel, Apple Numbers?

excuse me!I'm using Google Spreadsheets.
